# Regression analysis testing and $R^2$

Tags: regression, self-study, correlation, residuals

I am doing the question below.

[image]

For part a) i know that it is an F test that is needed. I have found SSE using the value of $s_\epsilon$ although i do not know how to find either SSR or SST to be able to finish the F test statistic. I know SST is related to the variance of the response variable, although i am unsure how to use this to find it.

For b) the formula should be $cor = \frac{cov(X_2,Y)}{(s_{X_2})(s_Y)}$. $s_{X_2}$ and $s_Y$ are provided although in order to find $cov$ it seems that i need either data or one of the SSR/SST values. How do i go about solving this?